# Kronecker delta in gnuplot for windows

Tags: gnuplot

Does anyone know whether there exists a mathematical artifact in gnuplot (for windows) that reproduces the Kronecker delta? As an example (taken from fortran): 0^(i-j) gives 1 if i=j, 0 otherwise since 0^(any number other than zero)=0 but 0^0= 1 in fortran; unfortunately, gnuplot gives 0 for all cases, so I need to search a different way. I've tried (1.e-15)^0 which should give 1 (while 1.e-15^(any other number is practically 0)), but then I get the message 'non-integer passed to boolean operator'. Likewise with 0^(1.e-15). Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ethans answer is the straight forward way.

But why does your attempt not work?

`0^(i-j)` does not work because `^` is the "bitwise exclusive OR" operator. Exponentiation is `**`, and I would take the absolute value:

```
0**abs(i-j)
```

See `help operators binary`.

Answer (score 3):

If `i` and `j` are integers, then `(i==j)` should be sufficient.  If you need to enforce a conversion to real values, you could wrap it in `real(i==j)` to give 0.0 or 1.0.